# Stackblitz: Can't Find Empty Package

Tags: angular, stackblitz

I am trying to get my Angular app to spin up in Stackblitz but it keeps throwing the error message 'Can't find package: [blank]:

[image: error message]

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expression-changed-error)

I have set project up in exactly the same way as VS Code and have tried googling to no avail - any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: what did you use as the starter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `providersection.component.ts` file, change the import of provider data to:

```
import providerData from '../../assets/data/provider-data.json';
```